# Really simple xcode array issue

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, uiimage

I'm programming a quiz app in xcode and I have 10 images which I want to use as UIImage views. I want to know how to create an array of all those images.

I also have a switch statement where I want to call 1 image from that array to be the UIImage. If you could explain how to call an image from an array as well I would be very grateful :)

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Can you include your code.

Comment: Assuming the images are in your app bundle and you need them one at a time, it's probably best to not load them all into an in-memory array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing **UIImages** in the array you can also store image names in array

```
NSArray *imagesArray = @[@"<image-name-1>",@"<image-name-2>",...,<image-name-10>];
```

when you want to get the image to set to **UIImageView**

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initwithFrame:<your-frame>];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imagesArray[<your-index>]];
```

Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call an object from an array, `objectAtIndex:` can do the job for you. It doesn't matter whether you store `UIImage` instances of `UIImageView` instances, this will work with any form of object.

Here's a little example that will call each item from the array using `objectAtIndex:`:

```
NSArray *_imageViews = ...

for (int idx; idx < _imageViews.count; idx++)
{
    UIImageView *_imageView = [_imageViews objectAtIndex:idx];

    /* do whatever you have to do with the image view */
}
```